# Laravel with with where eloquent

Tags: php

```
public function getGroupCategories() {

        $group_categories = GroupCategory::with('groupCategoriesTranslation', function($query) {
            $query->where('code', 'en');
        });

        return $group_categories;
    }
```

Hello,

I want to write this query in eloquent :

> SELECT * FROM group_categories AS gc INNER JOIN
>   group_categories_translation AS gct ON gc.id = gct.group_category_id
>   WHERE gct.code = 'en'

Laravel version is 5.3

Error :

> mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

It works when i use whereHas instead of with, but it returns only group_category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using wrong syntax. Correct syntax for with() is:

```
public function getGroupCategories() {

    $group_categories = GroupCategory::with(['groupCategoriesTranslation' => function($query){
        $query->where('code', 'en');
    }]);

    return $group_categories;
}
```

Comment: you missed get method after with. Thank you for response.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.